# total sum from previous column plus current column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have the table below:

```
 Id     Grade 1    Grade 2    Grade 3
  1       1           1         1  
  2       5           0         0
  3       3           1         5
```

I want the result as exactly as follows:

```
 Id     Grade 1    Grade 2    Grade 3      Total
  1       1           1         1            3
  2       5           0         0            8
  3       3           1         5            17
```

Total should be the sum from the current column + the previous total.

Is that possible in MYSQL?

Comment: Interesting question, but at least provide what have you tried... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate a Running Total in SqlServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

Comment: Is it `sql-server` as the tags indicate, or **MySQL** as you state in your question?? Please clarify !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
t.*,
@rolling_sum := @rolling_sum + `Grade 1` + `Grade 2` + `Grade 3` AS Total
from
Table1 t
, (select @rolling_sum := 0) var_init
order by id
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e82a/1/0)</kbd>

Another version:

```
select t.*,
(select sum([Grade 1] + [Grade 2] + [Grade 3]) from Table1 sub_t where sub_t.id <= t.id)
from Table1 t
order by id
```

Comment: got na errors: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ':'.

Comment: Maybe it's the frontend you're using? I can't reproduce the problem. Have you copy&pasted or rewritten?

Comment: Or maybe have a try with two statements instead of one: set @rolling_sum = 0;
select
t.*,
@rolling_sum := @rolling_sum + `Grade 1` + `Grade 2` + `Grade 3` AS Total
from
Table1 t
order by id;

Comment: Any difference in the error message? Have you copy&pasted?

Comment: Posted another version in my answer. But don't try it in sqlfiddle. This is for SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: The 1st total is null

Comment: @user2857350 Please have a try again. All is fixed now and tested on SQL Server too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.*, (@runtot := @runtot + `Grade 1` + `Grade 2` + `Grade 3`) AS Total
FROM Table1 A
,(SELECT @runtot:=0) c
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e82a/4)**

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method is summing values with a subselect statement as follows as described at tutorial titled [SQL running total sample](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-running-total-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

I also used a CTE statement to sum of individual grades as the sum of each line. Then I used the sum in the sub-select statement

```
;with cte as (
    select
        id,
        grade1,
        grade2,
        grade3,
        isnull(grade1,0) + isnull(grade2,0) + isnull(grade3,0) as linetotal
    from grade
)
select *, total = (select sum(ss.linetotal) from cte ss where ss.id <= cte.id)
from cte
```